# Do Unix/Linux systems generally have a "dump" directory?

Tags: backup, upgrade, tmp

A "middle" dump directory (path `Y`) to which one can to cut/copy-paste a few files from path `X` and then later cut/copy-paste these into path `Z` could be handy if someone is say upgrading a software but needs to save some specific files from before the upgrade and paste them back to the upgraded software (in case the saved files would naturally get deleted in upgrades).

Do Unix/Linux systems generally have a "dump" directory in which one can put files and that these files will either never get automatically deleted or will get automatically deleted in a universally standard, long time (say, 12 months)?

I assume that such a directory is *tmp* but I am not sure if generally all Unix/Linux systems have it or if there is any standard about it (such as 12 months for automatic deletion, if at all).

Comment: It's enough if you have `/tmp` there that you are currently using. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: `/var/cache`, `/var/lib` could also be used (and maybe `/var/spool`). it really depends on how do you interpret the data usage.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general "temporary" area that has guaranteed minimum retention time.  However there are two common directories used for this.

I would recommend `/var/tmp` for this purpose based on the [Linux File Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf) (pdf), which says:

> 3.18. `/tmp` : Temporary files
>
> 3.18.1. Purpose The `/tmp` directory must be made available for programs that require temporary files.
>
> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in `/tmp` are preserved between invocations of the program.

*and*

> 5.15. `/var/tmp` : Temporary files preserved between system reboots
> 5.15.1. Purpose The `/var/tmp` directory is made available for programs that require temporary files or directories that are preserved between system reboots. Therefore, data stored in `/var/tmp` is more persistent than data in `/tmp`.
>
> Files and directories located in `/var/tmp` must not be deleted when the system is booted. Although data stored in `/var/tmp` is typically deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended that deletions occur at a less frequent interval than `/tmp`.

Comment: Note that some non-Linux Unices don't really have `/var/tmp`.  OpenBSD, for example, has it only as a symbolic link to `/tmp`, and this is cleared on reboots and by the daily cleaning procedure (see e.g. [`hier(7)`](https://man.openbsd.org/hier)).

Comment: An example of a site-specific cleaner script is this from [4.3BSD /usr/adm/daily](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4.3BSD/usr/adm/daily): `cd /usr/tmp; find . ! -name . ! -name lost+found -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;` We changed `-mtime` to`-ctime` so that copies of old files did not disappear after one day.